# Значение по имени экземпляра класса

Tags: c#

Можно ли как-то получить данные из класса, используя только имя экземпляра класса. То есть

```
class Example
{
   int a;

   Example(int v)
   {
      a = v + 100;
   }
}

// Вызов в любом месте кода
Example ex = new Example(10);
Console.WriteLine(ex);  // Выведет 110;
```

Comment: `WriteLine`, внутри себя вызывает у параметра `.ToString` поэтому для нужного поведения достаточно переопределить этот метод

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Example
{
   int a;

   Example(int v)
   {
      a = v + 100;
   }

   public override string ToString() { return a.ToString(); }
}
```